# Add line break in textarea in a jade template

Tags: html, pug

I need to output an array content in a textarea in a jade template. It is something simple like this:

```
textarea
    each content
        {{this}}
```

But I need to add a linebreak after each element, as I want to display each element in a own line in the textarea. How do I add the linebreak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JADE you can use expressions like `\n`, `\s` or `\t` in "Unescaped Buffered Code". Take a look into the Docs: http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/

Here is an example Pen: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/XKMpBr

```
- var contents = {'line1': 'abcd\n', 'line2':'defg\n'}
textarea
   each content in contents
     !{content}
```